# Which IP address does a browser use if there’s more than one for the same URL?

Tags: dns

I noticed that when I ping a URL, more than one IP address may be returned by DNS:
[image]
I guess this means that there are two web servers serving the same FQDN.

I wonder which of the two would be used by a browser.  Is there any rule for this?

Any clarification much appreciated.

Comment: probably whatever comes first, chances are you'd see the results in different order over time

Comment: Chances are if you '/flushdns' and retry resolving, you'll get different IPs. There are many IPs, amongst other things, to forward you to the closest data-center. The browser tries one and if it fails it tries the second ( or the third etc )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no strict rule, as all addresses are equivalent and the program can use them in any order. Usually programs try all addresses in the list until one responds.

Values in DNS do not have an inherent order (and the A record itself has no priority field), so the DNS server might return the A records in any order; the expectation is that all addresses listed for a given name will be providing identical service. Often the answer is deliberately shuffled to provide some basic load-balancing¹. This might be done both by the authoritative server and/or by your local resolver.

¹ (There are a few reasons why even a single server having multiple addresses may perform better than the exact same setup with just one address.)

The program will usually use whatever order it gets from the OS, but the OS might shuffle the list again before returning it (just in case the DNS server did not).

There are really two lists at DNS level – one for IPv4 addresses (A records) and another for IPv6 (AAAA). Some programs (mainly web browsers) try both types in parallel, while others merge both into a single list which is sorted into broad categories (native global IPv6 addresses, then native IPv4, then private IPv6, etc).

Very old programs might only attempt the "first" IPv4 address (which address is "first" is unpredictable), as the older OS-provided "hostname lookup" functions couldn't return more than one. Such programs generally do not support anything but IPv4.

Comment: I have several that will use only the first IP address it got even if it's IPv6 and try no other. I also have some that will ask for IPv6 and ask for IPv4 if it got none but won't every try more than one address.

Answer (score 14):

In a nutshell there are two main mechanisms :

- DNS Round Robin is the main mechanism for choosing an
  IP address from the list returned by a DNS server, so that not all
  clients get the same IP address every time.
- Netmask ordering is another mechanism for further optimizing which
  IP address is for determining the closest result.

When a DNS server returns a a list of IP addresses for a DNS query,
it will attempt a round-robin method for reordering the list on each
successive query. This is based on the fact the most applications,
when receiving a list of IPs, will just pick up the first one,
only moving to the next if the previous one failed.

Round-robin DNS is described in
[RFC 1794 - DNS Support for Load Balancing](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;842197).

For IPv4, destination address selection is fairly simple and usually
done by selecting the first IP address returned by the DNS server.
This works well with DNS Round Robin as it lets the Server decide
what address the client will use by putting it at the top of the list.

IPv6 introduces a change in this behavior per
[RFC 3484](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt):

> The destination address selection algorithm takes a list of
> destination addresses and sorts the addresses to produce a new list.
> It is specified here in terms of the pair-wise comparison of addresses
> DA and DB, where DA appears before DB in the original list. The
> algorithm sorts together both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

The pair-wise comparison of destination addresses consists of ten
rules which should be applied in order.  If a rule determines a
result then the remaining rules are ignored, as subsequent rules
only act as tie-breakers for earlier rules.

There are 10 rules, but rule 9 should be considered :

```
Rule 9:  Use longest matching prefix.

When DA and DB belong to the same address family (both are IPv6 or
both are IPv4): If CommonPrefixLen(DA, Source(DA)) >
CommonPrefixLen(DB, Source(DB)), then prefer DA.  Similarly, if
CommonPrefixLen(DA, Source(DA)) < CommonPrefixLen(DB, Source(DB)),
then prefer DB.
```

The longest match is used, not just the first IP address off the list.
There is a change in behavior when IPv6 is installed, so the OS does
not just pull the first IP address off the list.

Reference :
[Advanced DNS Round Robin and Destination IP address selection on Windows Clients](https://www.agileit.com/news/advanced-dns-round-robin-and-destination-ip-address-selection-on-windows-clients/).

Comment: Note: RFC 3484 is obsoleted by RFC 6724.

Comment: The link for RFC 1794 doesn't work, and appears to be irrelevant.
Need to be clearer that Round-Robin also exists on Server-Side, and isn't relevant to the Original Question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I tested back around 2016:

- Your browser can do what it wants, and it's likely their behaviour may differ.
- Your browser can rely on the OS to provide it with an IP ("gethostbyname").
- Back in 2016, Linux & NetBSD would return a randomly chosen address.
- Back in 2016, some, but not all, Windows 10 machines would return a randomly chosen address. Older versions of Windows would return the first one in the list.

I expect now all Windows 10/11 machines would randomly pick an IP.